# How would you babyproof a steam radiator that's recessed into the wall?

Tags: plumbing, woodworking, carpentry, radiator

We just moved into a rental house (so my options for modifying it are limited) that has approximately 24" x 24" steam radiators recessed into the walls. They're surrounded by a bit of molding.

We'll only be living here for one winter (maybe 6 months of heating) so I don't want to invest a huge amount, but I also want something that isn't a total eyesore. My plan right now is to make something simple with some pine boards and wood or white vinyl lattice from the hardware store. I think they also sell blankets for this purpose, and maybe I could staple them to the trim or something. **Any other ideas?**

Legally the landlord is required to provide covers for them "within 4 months" which is a ridiculous timeline and I don't want to wait that long.

[image]

Comment: Agree - some 2x2s with wire/plastic mesh, zip-tied (might want metal zip ties) to those grates.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider a common fireplace screen, which I'd attach to the wall in the drywall area (fairly easily repaired). You may need a spacer to account for the depth of the baseboard. Your local or online home improvement center probably offers several inexpensive options.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coxandcox.co.uk%2Fnew-grey-metal-fire-screen%2F&psig=AOvVaw0B-mAQc2gW9HbOXvP3urwv&ust=1695146920193000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjhxqFwoTCNjd1sLgtIEDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAp)</sub>

Comment: or build/buy a radiator cabinet. Either way you may want to think about affixing the protection to the wall, or a base, so the kid can't knock it over. Kids start trying to climb things fairly early.

Answer (score 1):

Drop an appropriate-sized end-table in front of it. Either choose a design that suits "baby fence" yet open for airflow directly (such as Mission/Craftsmen style) or attach a screen to the back (or side against the wall/radiator) of it.